# Linux Centos 7 - Apache using different version than installed PHP version

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos7

Replacing the PHP version that is being used by Apache on a Linux Centos 7 server.

I am using a Linux Centos 7 server, where I have installed PHP 7.2.24, when I use the command: php --version it displays the correct PHP version:

[Current PHP version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtL6w.png)

When I display PHP info, Apache is using PHP Version 5.6.40.

I have taken a look in the .conf file, located at: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf which has the following lines in the file:

[httpd.conf content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJHW7.png)

This lead me to opening /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-phpmodules.conf, which has the following content:

[phpmodules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSPSS.png)

My idea is to to edit the LoadModule line in /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-phpmodules.conf to load the PHP 7 module. Is this the right thing to do?

The next challenge I face, is to track down the module name & path I have to replace it with.

When I run the command: yum list installed *php*, it displays the PHP packages, but it doesn't look anywhere near the module name or path that I can use. How can I track down the module name & path to replace in httpd-phpmodules.conf (if this is the correct location to replace it).

[yumlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP3sZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I track down the module name

A method I use to easily search for files is ‘locate’.

```
sudo apt install mlocate -y ; sudo updatedb
```

Then, search for php:

```
locate php
```

Multiple entries will return.
Simply execute a valid looking php executable, and check if that is the version u want.

Comment: This is very helpfull, thank you! I have found the location of PHP7.2. Now, I'm searching for a file similar to the current lib5php.so (mostly searching on .so files).

It seems I can only find .SO files in: /opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules, which contains modules like SimpleXML, xmlreader, etc. But not anything like the PHP libary as the current version.

Comment: I don’t know, but perhaps the .so file is unrequired, or you might need to install another php package..